# D-Link DIR-300 wireless router on DD-WRT as a repeater

Tags: wireless-router, home-networking, dir-300

- OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- Host router: [TP-Link WR841ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TL-WR841ND.html) 300Mbps Wireless N Router. ---> [Emulator](http://www.tplink.com/resources/simulator/TL-WR841ND_V8/Index.htm)
- Repeater: [D-Link DIR-300](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/product/dir-300-wireless-g-router) 54Mbps Wireless G Router ---> [Emulator](http://suporte.dlink.com.br/suporte/arquivos/DIR-300/emulador/bsc_wan.php)

**Scenario:**

I have already flashed the DIR-300 with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) firmware successfully and set it up as a repeater. The mode I'm using is "Client Bridge". I'm also getting a full 5-bar signal.

**Problem:**

I'm subscribed to a 10Mbps package from my ISP. I am only getting around half the speed or less from  my DIR-300 repeater (anywhere between 2 to 5 Mbps) . On the other hand, I am able to get full 10 Mbps speed from the host TP-Link router when I'm close to it. Is this because I'm using a 54 Mbps wireless G router? Is there a way to fix it so that I can get full 10 Mbps speed?

Alternative solution if the above cannot be fixed:

If I purchase the [TL-WA850RE](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TL-WA850RE.html) **300Mbps Universal WiFi Range Extender**, will this provide full 10 Mbps speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some speed is lost when going through a repeater because of the distance it travels but not as much as you are talking about. I would suggest setting up the D-Link as the main router and see what speeds it gets, if it doesn't improve then it is definitely the router.

Comment: I purchased the TL-WA850RE 300Mbps Universal WiFi Range Extender and I'm getting a 10 Mbps connection speed (full speed). Also, placing the old D-Link wireless G router at a higher altitude gave 70 to 80% of the speed (I overlooked altitude's significance), but the TL-WA850RE I bought gave 100% (also at a high altitude, around 3 meters above ground level). Thank you GeekyDewd.

Answer (score 2):

All "repeater" modes sacrifice half of the wi-fi speed for talking to the host and its clients simultaneously.
See: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge (just above "Troubleshooting" section)